# Project has 144 fatal failures after running in new XCode 6

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode6

I used XCode6 beta4 to develop my project via obj-c and Swift. After I've installed GM version every

```
self.view.addSubview(startButton)
```

Highlighted and also these lines are highlighted

```
scene.view.paused
self.scene.removeAllActions()
self.view.bounds
```

are SpriteKit classes changed or it's my fault or it's GM's bug?

error is SKView/SKScene does not have a member **** , but I checked it, it HAS those members.

[image]

Comment: Show us the specific error message you are getting, as well as an example of a full line of code that triggers it.

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: @s1ddok Could you give the exact error message for `self.view.addSubview(startButton)` without blanking parts out using asterisks?

Comment: added screenshot, hope it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know I've seen several effective duplicates already, but I'm not finding them at the moment, so here's a quick answer.

This has to do with how object parameters, return values, and properties in APIs are imported from ObjC to Swift. Earlier in the Xcode 6 beta period, all object params/returns/properties were imported as implicitly unwrapped optionals; e.g.

```
// in SKScene:
var view: UIView!
// in SKNode:
var children: [AnyObject]!
```

With an implicitly unwrapped optional (IUO), you can address `view` directly (so code like `self.view.bounds` is legal). It might not exist, in which case you'll get a crash. And some operations aren't possible on an IUO type that are possible on the type it contains. The best practice for IUOs is to check them for nil, using constructs like optional chaining and optional binding, before working with their contents.

The ObjC-to-Swift importer has to do this for all properties/params/returns that are pointers to ObjC objects because syntactically any pointer is allowed to be `nil`, even if in practice it will never be. Testing for `nil` gets kinda cumbersome for APIs like `SKNode.children` that are never `nil` (it's an empty array in the no-children case).

Over the last few betas and the Xcode 6 GM, Apple audited several frameworks so that imported object pointers that can possibly be `nil` (like `UIViewController.view`) import as explicit Optionals:

```
// SKScene
var view: UIView?
```

And object pointers that will never be `nil` import as non-optional types:

```
// SKNode
var children: [AnyObject]
```

This means that you can safely reference `node.children` without worrying about a crash and without needing to check it for `nil`. But now that `scene.view` is explicitly optional, you *must* check it for nil before using it.

Depending on the scenario, you might choose any of several ways to test or otherwise deal with an optional:

- Force unwrap: `self.view!.bounds.size`
- Optional chaining: `self.view?.bounds.size`
- Optional binding: `if let view = self.view { /* do something with */ view.bounds.size }`
- Chaining and Binding: `if let size = self.view?.bounds.size { /* do something with */ size }`

Read up on [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_483) in *The Swift Programming Language* for details on the advantages and disadvantages of each.

Comment: thanks! i'm trying to fix all the issues with randomly putting ! or ? until failure is gone. but i'll dig into this subject a bit later.

Comment: [Randomly sprinkling punctuation in your code](https://xenresources.com/attachments/picard-facepalm-jpg.2169/?d=1400710854) may make Xcode stip complaining, but not knowing what's in your code and why will surely cause you trouble later.

Comment: As @rickster says **don't do that** unless you want unexpected crashes in your code. Do not explicitly (use !) unwrap any value which can ever, under any circumstances be nil. And when you test the optional you will need to handle the case where it is nil—which is actually the whole point behind optionals, handling failures correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your fault really.  The Swift team went through and cleaned up the use of optionals in the frameworks.  In some cases, implicitly unwrapped optionals (declared with `!`) became regular optionals (declared with `?`).

The `view` is now an optional declared with `?` instead of an implicitly unwrapped optional declared with `!`.  You now need to unwrap the value when using it:

```
self.view?.bounds.size
```